# maven archetype:create-from-project did not contain the package

Tags: maven, archetypes

here is my folder structer:

```
pom.xml
src
  ├───api
  │   │   pom.xml
  │   └───src
  │       ├───main
  │       │   ├───java
  │       │   │    └───api
  │       │   │         |---MyEntity.java
  │       │   └───resources
  │       │       └───META-INF
  │———————|beans.xml
```

when i used the mvn archetype:create-from-project, it works well, and next i create a proj using the archetype

but in the generated-arch folder it didn't contain the package, i mean , the folder stucter looks like this:

```
pom.xml
src
  ├───api
  │   │   pom.xml
  │   └───src
  │       ├───main
  │       │   ├───java
  │       │   │    └──MyEntity.java
  │       │   └───resources
  │       │       └───META-INF
  │———————|beans.xml
```

what's wrong with it ?